# How can I use the if statement in Python with an array?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the following statement:

```
if any(dy) < 0:

     print 'do something'
```

I can see in the array that there a lots of elements < then 0 but still it seems like the program does can't read them and execute the print command. I suppose that is because dy is an array. 
How can I remedy this problem?

Comment: In *plain Python* `any()` is a built-in function that returns a True or False boolean value, and that value is *never* smaller than `0`. But given the fact that you use the term `array` here makes me wonder if you are using `numpy`, which *also* comes with an [`any()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html). Which one are you using?

Comment: is this a python array or a numpy array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
if any(i < 0 for i in dy):
    print 'do something'
```

The `i < 0 for i in dy` part is a generator, which will yield some `True` values when iterated over if there are values less than 0 in `dy`. The `any` function then iterates over the generator, and returns `True` if it encounters any `True`s in the generators output, meaning that there is a value(s) less than 0 in `dy`. In your current way, `any` will return `True`, which is equivalent to 1, or `False`, which is equivalent to 0, both of which are not less than 0, so your `print` is never executed.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you explain *why* it should be used that way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried to do exactly that below. Otherwise, I wouldn't have posted.

Comment: Thanks, yes. And the reason that it never worked for the OP is because `any(dy)` returns `True` (`== 1`) or `False` (`== 0`). That's never going to be smaller than 0.

Comment: Even if `dy` was all zeros, and `any()` returned `False`, it'd be *equal*, not smaller, to zero.

Comment: How can I use the negative elements in that array for a subsequent calculation? I only want the negative values!

Comment: @Anti `[i for i in dy if i < 0]`

Comment: Nope, sorry..that does not work. Any more ideas anyone?

Comment: It does not select exclusively the negative values. I only need the negative values.

Comment: @Anti `[i for i in range(-10, 10) if i < 0]` gives `[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]`. Does your list contain strings or something like that?

Comment: No only numeric values. I'll try again later. Thanks 4 the help.

Comment: @Anti I'm glad it works. Could you please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer, so that other users know this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `any` function simply tests if there is a single true value in the passed expression:

```
any(i < 0 for i in dy) # need to use a generator or list comprehension
```